# Como asignar el valor de un combo por un valor con javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un problema a la hora de asignar un valor a un combo cuando lo muestro en mi formulario. El código seria el siguiente.

```
//tengo mi función de donde recibo los valores desde otra parte
miFuncion=function(idorden,valor){
 $('#idorden').val(idorden);
 document.getElementById("s1").value = val(valor);
}
```

y en el html

```
<div>
 <label for="idorden">Numero de Orden</label>
 <input type="text" id="idorden" class="form-control">
</div>
<form id='tambor' >
 <select id='s1' >
  <option value='1' > opción 1 </option>
  <option value='2' > opción 2 </option>
  <option value='3' > opción 3 </option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Ahora, puedo ver el valor del "idorden" pero no me muestra la opción del combo que según debería estar mostrando en "s1", y checando en el modo de desarrolladór en el navegador me muestra el siguiente error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: val is not defined".

De antemano agradezco su ayuda. Excelente día.

Comment: El error es esto: `document.getElementById("s1").value = val(valor);` Debería ser `document.getElementById("s1").value = valor;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es la asignación del value en esta linea

> document.getElementById("s1").value = val(valor);

Lo que deberías hacer es seguir usando JQuery para setear el valor como lo haces con el input de esta forma.

```js
miFuncion = function(idorden,valor){
    $('#idorden').val(idorden);
    $("#s1").val(valor);
}
//funcion de prueba
miFuncion(5,3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <label for="idorden">Numero de Orden</label>
 <input type="text" id="idorden" class="form-control">
</div>
<form id='tambor' >
 <select id='s1' >
  <option value='1' > opción 1 </option>
  <option value='2' > opción 2 </option>
  <option value='3' > opción 3 </option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la observación es muy útil.

Comment: Si mi respuesta es la solución que buscabas, marcala como  la mejor.

Comment: ya le puse palomita, gracias